# Getting a table from my database to display in a JPanel

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jpanel

I am pretty new to Java, and I am dabbling in a small Point of Sale program just to teach myself how it works. My goal is to get a table from my database which stores the inventory data and display it within my JPanel I made. I thought what I did would work, but when I click my Load Database button, nothing displays. This is the first time I am working with java.sql so my knowledge of it is very basic. It may even be an obvious issue that I don't even see. Here's what I'm working with.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class tableTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tableTest window = new tableTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public tableTest() {

        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 804, 484);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 768, 382);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton tableBtn = new JButton("Load Data");
        tableBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {

                    String tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM inventory";

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bazaar", "root", "password");
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(tableQuery);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }

                catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        tableBtn.setBounds(350, 411, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tableBtn);
    }
}
```

Just edited the code to make it a bit more simple to look at. I have data in the database, so I know that isn't the issue, but I cannot figure out how to get that data to display in the table.

Comment: I would recommend posting [mcve]. Test with hard-coded data to check where the problem is : reading from DB or displaying it.

Comment: I would verify that there is data in the database

Comment: The problem is probably in `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` method. Read tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcswing.html.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this whole tutorial seems to be based off the CoffeeTableModel class, and using the getContentsOfCoffeesTable() method. However, they don't show the class or method in the tutorial, so needless to say, I have no clue how the getContentsOfCoffeesTable() method works.